# deploy maven application in JBoss not work

Tags: maven, jboss

I'm developing my first maven application and now i have this trouble, i performed  the following commands

mvn compile
mvn package 
mvn jboss-as-deploy

the deploy process ends without errors but in my JBOSS_HOME\standalone\deployments i don't find the .war

why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set targetDir option (maybe the default is overriden in your environoment?). See http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html.

Answer (score 0):

The `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments` directory is not where deployments are stored. If you look in that directory there is a README file that explains it's what the directory is used for.

The `jboss-as-maven-plugin` uses the deployment API's to deploy the content to the server. This generally ends up in `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/data/content` for a standalone server. Though you really shouldn't be doing anything with files in that directory.